# How can I modify wp_nav_menu with walker?

Tags: menus, walker

I would like my wp_nav_menu to output in the format for jquery ui:

```
<h3>Section 1</h3>
<div>
<p>
Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
</p>
</div>
<h3>Section 2</h3>
<div>
<p>
Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
suscipit faucibus urna.
</p>
</div>
```

The list has two levels. I've successfully changed the top level, but I'm having trouble with the second level. How can I do this? Is there an easier way than extending the walker class?

Comment: Showing your code and what you've tried is a prerequisite to asking questions on this site. Else it will be closed as "do this job for me"-question.

Comment: Why are you using `wp_nav_menu` to produce something that doesn't really look like a menu?

Comment: @s_ha_dum This is the format used by jQuery UI by default for their accordion menus.

Comment: @kaiser I've solved my own question. I'd post the answer, but it says I can't for 8 hours.

Comment: @Jordy Just post it in 8 hours. You can later mark it as solution.